# Magento2: Error client denied by server configuration:

Tags: error, magento2

After I migrate data on magento2 from 1.9.1, I get an error on the home page, admin is functional, error is

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

In /var/log/httpd error_log  client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/magento2/app/etc/config.php
```

Comment: That error is not related to your redirect problem. Issue seems something else.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to be about a misconfiguration on your server instead of Magento